# flutter downloader and path provider on ios

Tags: flutter, path

I have managed to make flutter downloader and the path provider work on android but it won't work on ios saying that this is a android only operation , what's wrong ?
here is the code :

```
 secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Download',
          color: Colors.green,
          icon: Icons.arrow_circle_down,
          onTap: () async {
            final status = await Permission.storage.request();
            if (status.isGranted) {
              final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
              final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                  url: f.url,
                  savedDir: externalDir.path,
                  showNotification: true,
                  openFileFromNotification: true);
            } else {
              toast('Permission Denied');
            }
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS, after having permission, you should use `final externalDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` since `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is not supported for iOS.

You can do an OS check:

```dart
var externalDir;
if (Platform.isIOS) { // Platform is imported from 'dart:io' package
  externalDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
}
```

Comment: will this affect the flutter downloader ? or should it work fine on both platforms ?